# Xamarin MvvmCross: View Model within View Model possible with corresponding .Droid View?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on a project which has a ViewModel which grabs some info and displays some text and a function in the .Droid View which grabs a base64, converts it into an image and then places it in an ImageView in the layout, no big deal.

The same ViewModel for the layout gets a list of objects which is then put into a MvxListView (ListItem class extending MvxViewModel) with corresponding layout of a ListItem with some text from variables set upon instantiation in a foreach loop, all text.

BUT each ListItem needs to display an image from a base64 string provided by the server just like the one picture mentioned earlier. Now my problem is that in order to convert this base64 string to an image, I need to do this in the .Droid View as the package Android.Util has the Base64 class I need to do this.

I do not clearly know how to do this as the ImageView instances are part of the ListItems which are added programmaticly and I therefore do not know what layout id is assigned to each ListItem ImageView. So I'm thinking each ListItem might need their own .Droid View within the parent page .Droid View which they are a part of. Then each ListItem .Droid View can get, convert and assign the image to their ImageView.

Long story short, I want to be able to have instances of a ViewModel and their corresponding .Droid Views within a ViewModel tied to their ListItem layouts.

Does anybody here then have an idea of how this can be achieved, if it's even possible or if I can solve this in another (hopefully simpler) way?

**The ListItem class** located in the main ViewModel:

```
public class EventListItemViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public Action LoadImageDelegate { get; set; }

    private string eventTitle;
    public string EventTitle
    {
        get { return eventTitle; }
        set { eventTitle = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => EventTitle); }
    }

    private string timeUntil;
    public string TimeUntil
    {
        get { return timeUntil; }
        set { timeUntil = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TimeUntil); }
    }

    private string imgUrl;

    public string ImgUrl
    {
        get { return imgUrl; }
        set {

            imgUrl = value;
            //LoadImageDelegate?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Foreach loop** which currently instantiates the ListItems:

```
foreach (Event e in Events)
            {
                CompleteEventList.Add(new EventListItemViewModel { EventTitle = e.Name, TimeUntil = "0 h", ImgUrl = e.ImgUrl});
            }
```

Comment: I think you can use a provider to solve this. Create an interface to convert base64 to images in you core project, and implement it in the Droid project. Then you wouldn't need a new view for each one. You can just call the conversion class when you prepare your view model.

Comment: How would that work with setting the source of each ImageView from .Dorid? How do I call this from .Core in the foreach loop? And in that case how will the .Droid part know the layout id for that ListItem?